# Limit of complex sum

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left| e^{2\pi i k
/n} - e^{2\pi i (k-1)/n} \right|
$$
Please help me with this one. I can't figure it out how to break the modulus as it's coming very large.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\big|e^{2\pi i(k-1)/n}\big|\cdot \big|e^{2\pi i/n}-1\big|=\sum_{k=1}^n\big|e^{2\pi i/n}-1\big|=n\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}}=2\cdot n\big|\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\big|\to 2\pi.$

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $n$, the $e^{2\pi i k/n}$, $1 \leq k \leq n$, are the $n$ angles of a regular $n$-agon enscribed on the unit circle $z = 1$ in the complex plane. So intuitevely you can see that each of the term in the sum are equal because each term is equal to the lenght of a side of the polygon. This is indeed true :

$$
|e^{2\pi i k/n} - e^{2\pi i (k-1)/n}| = |e^{2\pi i (k-1)/n}||e^{2\pi i /n} - 1|
=|e^{2\pi i /n} - 1|.
$$

Now

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^n |e^{2\pi i k/n} - e^{2\pi i (k-1)/n}| &=
n |e^{2\pi i /n} - 1| = n \sqrt{ (\cos(2\pi  /n) - 1)^2 + \sin^2(2\pi  /n)} \\
&=  n\sqrt{\cos^2(2\pi  /n) - 2 \cos(2\pi  /n) + 1 + \sin^2(2\pi  /n) } \\
&= n\sqrt{2 (1-\cos(2\pi  /n)} \\
&= 2n \sin(\pi  /n) = 2\pi \frac{\sin(\pi  /n)}{\pi n} \rightarrow 2\pi
\end{aligned}
$$

thanks to the formula $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2 (x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$ and to the fact that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1$ as $x$ tends to zero.

And this limit is what we should have expected: as $n$ goes to infinity the polygon has more and more sides so it approximates better and better the circle $z=1$ of circonference $2\pi$

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out $e^{2\pi ik /n}$ (which has modulus $1$) and  simplify the sum as $n|1-e^{-2\pi i/n}|$. Use the fact that $e^{z}=1+z+o(z)$ as $x \to 0$ we see that the limit is $2\pi$.

More details: $e^{2\pi ik /n}-e^{2\pi i(k-1) /n}=e^{2\pi ik /n} [1-e^{-2\pi i/n}]$ so $|e^{2\pi ik /n}-e^{2\pi i(k-1) /n}|=|e^{2\pi ik /n}|| 1-e^{-2\pi i/n}|=| 1-e^{-2\pi i/n}|$. Now you see that the terms of this sum do not depend on $k$ at all! There are $n$ terms so you get $n  | 1-e^{-2\pi i/n}|$. So what you have to find is limit of $n  | [1-e^{-2\pi i/n}]|$. We can use the Taylor expansion of $e^{z}$ for this.

Comment: please be more descriptive, I can't still understand it.

Comment: @SoumajitDas I hope the answer is clear now.